# Calculating ICC using random intercept and residual variances

Tags: multilevel-analysis, intraclass-correlation

I have seen many posts refer to the calculation of the ICC by utilizing the variance of the random intercept and the residual variance from a multilevel model. Does anyone have this formula handy?

Answer (score 4):

You can find the formula on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intraclass_correlation#Modern_ICC_definitions:_simpler_formula_but_positive_bias).  It is:
$$
\text{ICC} = \frac{\sigma^2_{\text{intercepts}}}{\sigma^2_\text{intercepts} + \sigma^2_\text{residuals}}
$$